# Stanford NLP Parser gives different result (sentiment) for same statement used in Kaggle Movie review

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, stanford-nlp, kaggle

I am working on Kaggle Movie Sentiment Analysis and I found the movie reviews has been parsed using Standford Parser.
On exploring the dataset I found same statement giving different setiments-

```
their parents , wise folks that they are ,  2
their parents , wise folks that they are    3

Genuinely unnerving .   3
Genuinely unnerving 1
```

where english is the parsed data and the digit belongs to sentiment.
Now if you check the line just comma and a dot is the difference rest is same but both belongs to different sentiment which is raising a lot of trouble for me to classify.

What should I do in text classification to avoid such problem, if I ignore the duplicate and use the already added sentiment , my classification goes horribly wrong, so what should be the way to solve such scenarios.

Comment: You could remove punctuation before doing the sentiment analysis.

Comment: I tried so naturally I am not adding the duplicate rows in my dataset after removing punctuations, but now  classification is very poor but on adding all the data considering duplicates as well do better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using Bag of Words and the comma and the dot are one of your features (a column in your `X` matrix).

```
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+----+
|    Document/Features    | Genuinely | unnerving | .  |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+----+
|  Genuinely unnerving .  |         1 |         1 | 1  |
|  Genuinely unnerving    |         1 |         1 | 0  |
+-------------------------+-----------+-----------+----+
```

An ideal algorithm should learn wether these features are relevant or not. For example in the case of Logistic Regression your algorithm would assign a really small weight to the corresponding column, and therefore a `1` or a `0` in that column won't change the outcome of the prediction. So you would have something like:

```
"Genuinely unnerving ." -> 0.5*1 + -2.3*1 + 0.000001*1 -> Negative
"Genuinely unnerving  " -> 0.5*1 + -2.3*1 + 0.000001*0 -> Also negative
```

In your case it looks like they are having some small effect. Is this really a problem? You have found some special cases were it seems wrong but by looking at the data the algorithm found that sentences with a dot are more negative that sentences without one. May be you should trust that statistically speaking, a dot can change the meaning of a sentence.

It can also happen that you have bad training data or a bad overfitting model. If you really think something is wrong, then you can impose this knowledge on the model by representing the sentences so that they are indistinguishable, for example by ignoring some punctuation.

I think it would be wrong to leave all punctuations out at once, for example a `!` could be representative of very positive sentiment when accompanied by the word `yes`, if you strip it from your sentence you would be hiding the model valuable information. But may be it is just the opposite and `!` is negative in most cases, so it gets a high negative weight after training, which confuses the model when predicting `yes!!!` like sentences. In this case you could represent your sentence as bigrams, so that the model can separately weight the effect of a single `!` and a `(yes, !)` combination.

So in resume, you should try different models and ways to represent your data and see what works.